# Doubt regarding Islamic bussiness rule

Tags: business

Assalam o alaikum,
I got to know from Zaid Patel lecture on ' Tijarat ke islami osool ' video no. 20 and also from Shiekh Abu Umar Abdulaziz lecture on ' fiqh of running bussiness...' video no. 16 that in Beassalam(manufacturing) practice debt from both sides(seller as well as buyer) is haraam.
Does this applies for trading and service also?
Video links=https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YSuQfOQa4tc&list=PLjc7oSoRGqpFc2O0LN7eoP00fRdVEZ03V&index=20

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=L5YPGooCM7g&list=PLBy4GHLUPhqW-N8y9Brb1C5YNziP-ynXt&index=16

Answer (score -1):

Dept is halal. Anybody can agree with a commercial partner to pay later or in rates.

What is haram is to take any kind of interest, be it per time or payment of a higher price.

Comment: Do not sell what you do not possess - https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3503